# How to create an uppercase version of a String in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It is possible using Swift to create an uppercase version of a String with

```
let str = "Hello World!"
print(str.uppercased())
```

This code will print "HELLO WORLD!" into the Xcode console. But how do you create an uppercase of a String like the following using SwiftUI?

```
Text("Hello World!")
```

Comment: `Text("Hello World!".uppercased())`

Comment: This has nothing to do with swiftUI.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this simply in this way

```
Text("Hello World!".uppercased())
```

For `LocalizedStringKey` you can use this.

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("keyName")).textCase(.uppercase)
```

Comment: What about if you are using a LocalizedStringKey?

Comment: @Maksymilian Tomczyk answer is better since it operates on the view side not the data side, also it can be composed into a Style, so even if you're not LocalizedStringKey then it's still the way to do it.

Answer (score 41):

For those who want to use LocalizedStringKey. Since iOS 14 you can use `.textCase(.uppercase)` on Text.

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("keyName"))
  .textCase(.uppercase)
```