# SwiftUI: Uppercase a localized string for a view, e.g. `Text`?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

Using Xcode beta 6 and SwiftUI, creating a `Text` view using a **>localized<** string, how can I uppercase it **without having to make the localized string value uppercased**? I guess I want a `ViewModifier` for changing case, but it does not seem to exist?

`Text("SignIn.Body.Instruction".uppercased())` will uppercase the localization **key**, so that will not work, as instructed in this [SO question about uppercasing a non-localized string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945195/how-to-create-an-uppercase-version-of-a-string-in-swiftui).

Comment: Does localizedCapitalized not work ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414885-localizedcapitalized#declarations

Comment: @yawnobleix that is a completely different thing :D. This is a `SwiftUI` question. We _cannot_ change the string itself because it is referring to the name of a _key_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is now possible with all new [`textCase` ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/textcase(_:)) (Xcode 12 Beta 3), like so:

```swift
Text("SignIn.Body.Instruction")
    .textCase(.uppercase)
```

Or `lowercase`:

```swift
Text("SignIn.Body.Instruction")
    .textCase(.lowercase)
```

Answer (score 11):

How about using the `smallCaps` modifier for `Font`? E.g., `Text("Hello World").font(Font.body.smallCaps())` will render `"HELLO WORLD"`, but the underlying string will retain its proper localized capitalization for the purposes of accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Localise it manually and then uppercase it.

```
extension String {
    func toUpperCase() -> String {
        return localized.uppercased(with: .current)
    }
    private var localized : String {
        return NSLocalizedString( self, comment:"")
    }
}

Text("SignIn.Body.Instruction".toUpperCase())
```

Comment: `NSLocalizedString( self, comment:"")` not a good idea, because the key argument to NSLocalizedString is not constant. Thus genstrings and Xcode Editor -> Export for Localization cannot pick it up. Short term it may be convenient, but it will bite you when later you have to find all strings to localise in the app manually!

Comment: You don't want to use uppercased(), that is meant for programmatic strings, not user-facing strings, as it does not take into account locale.
See `.uppercased(with: Locale.current))`

Comment: I didn't know about .uppercased(with: Locale.current)) thanks for the tip. As for the issue with genstrings your point is quite valid, however in SwiftUI I hope to not have to use my method very often, mostly the localisation will be handled by Text() automatically.